# Regular Expression for splitting a String by Upper Case only words in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have this...

```
 String bigWord = "I AM LOUD But also sensitive";
 String[] words = bigWord.split("[^A-Z| ]");
```

I want the first entry in that list to be 'I AM LOUD' and the second to be 'But also sensitive'.

The above RegEx almost works but it captures the first letter of the second entry..

"I AM LOUD B"

How can I fix that?

Comment: Should the *space* character after LOUD be in the first string or the second string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Matcher` class so you can get the groups easily.

```
      String bigWord = "I AM LOUD But also sensitive";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z ]+)? ([A-Z]?.*)");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bigWord);
      while(matcher.find()){
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
         System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
      }
```

Output:

```
I AM LOUD
But also sensitive
```

The key in the regexp is:

`A group of uppercased words` `an space` `A group of mixed chars`